# how can I perform conditional splitting with exceptions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to split a string into sentences.

But there is some exceptions that I did not expected:

```
str = "Text... Text. Text! Text? UPPERCASE.UPPERCASE. Name. Text."
```

Desired split:

```
split = ['Text...', 'Text.', 'Text!', 'Text?', 'UPPERCASE.UPPERCASE. Name.', 'Text.']
```

How can I do using regex python

My efforts so far,

```
str = "Text... Text. Text! Text? UPPERCASE.UPPERCASE. Name. Text."
split = re.split('(?<=[.|?|!|...])\s', str)
print(split)
```

I got:

```
['Text...', 'Text.', 'Text!', 'Text?', 'UPPERCASE.UPPERCASE.', 'Name.', 'Text.']
```

Expect:

```
['UPPERCASE.UPPERCASE. Name.']
```

The `\s` in `[A-Z]+\. Name` do not split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
(?<=[.?!])(?<![A-Z]\.(?=\s+Name))\s+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9YYGnM/1). Details:

- `(?<=[.?!])` - a positive lookbehind that requires `.`, `?` or `!` immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?<![A-Z]\.(?=\s+Name))` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is an uppercase letter and a `.` followed with 1+ whitespaces + `Name` immediately to the left of the current location (note the `+` is used in the *lookahead*, that is why it works with Python `re`, and `\s+` in the lookahead is necessary to check for the `Name` presence after whitespace that will be matched and consumed with the next `\s+` pattern below)
- `\s+` - one or more whitespace chars.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/srcUiI):

```py
import re
text = "Text... Text. Text! Text? UPPERCASE.UPPERCASE. Name. Text."
print(re.split(r'(?<=[.?!])(?<![A-Z]\.(?=\s+Name))\s+', text))
# => ['Text...', 'Text.', 'Text!', 'Text?', 'UPPERCASE.UPPERCASE. Name.', 'Text.']
```

Comment: Sorry for my stupid question.
The name must be "Text" also not specific.

But your answer helped me to solve that problem.

Thank you very much!!